# launching Theia based electron app (artifact/package) isn't working

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Almost new in using playwright. Exploring the things and checking what we can do with this tool.

I am trying to launch our Theia based electon app in Ubuntu 18.04 with below source.

```
const { _electron: electron } = require('playwright');
//const { _electron } = require('playwright');


//import { test, expect, Page } from '@playwright/test';

(async () => {
      // Launch Electron app.
      const electronApp = await electron.launch('./my_executable_file_path');
                                               //this executable is an artifact/packgae

})();

test.describe('New Todo', () => {
      test('should allow me to add todo items', async ({ page }) => {
      //let's not do anything before the app launch.
  });
```

});

In my `package.json` file, i have this already

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.20.2",
```

I can successfully run test cases based on the browser but not able to launch the electron app.

```
electron.launch: Cannot find module 'electron/index.js'
```

We don't have this index.js in our jenkins generated artifact.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I launched electron successfully

```
const electronApp = await _electron.launch({
        args: ['theia-electron-main.js'],
        cwd: 'cube-electron/apps/studio/electron/scripts'
     });
```